# Selenium: Element not found on session

Tags: java, selenium-rc

I am using Selenium RC Java. 
Req: To click print all links in a page which ends with '?product=' and then click one by one.

The links doesn't have IDs. Therefore I am using XPATH.

Please check my code.

```
selenium.open("http://s4.com");
int count= selenium.getXpathCount("xpath=//a[contains(@href, '?product=')]").intValue();
for(int i=1;i<count;i++)
{
  selenium.click("xpath=//a[contains(@href, '?product=')]["+ i +"]");
}
```

This returns

```
14:19:27.907 INFO - Command request: getXpathCount[xpath=//a[contains(@href, '?product=')], ] on session e4da58d4bf7d4eb6a7aa8238135fc969
14:19:28.950 INFO - Got result: OK,4 on session e4dawerdfsdf34aa8238135fc969
4
14:19:28.956 INFO - Command request: click[xpath=//a[contains(@href, '?product=')][1], ] on session e4dasdfs3434erererdf38135fc969
14:19:29.994 INFO - Got result: ERROR: Element xpath=//a[contains(@href, '?product=')][1] not found on session e4da58d4bf7d4eb6afsd343fdsf135fc969
```

I want to print the links too. Is there any way?

Comment: Since you didn't include samples of the actual links, I'm going to guess that the number at the end doesn't match the format you are looking for.

Comment: Hi bob, The links are,  http://s4.com/home/index?product=1 , http://s4.com/home/index?product=2 and soon. This is our staging site

Comment: Hi,

I just found the right code

used,
  selenium.click("xpath=//a[contains(@href,'?product="+ i +"')]");

It worked!

Thanks...Shario